# Shrink non-bootable LUKS LVM

Tags: lvm, disk-encryption, luks

I'm importing a VMWare OVA whose second disk uses LUKS and configured to use 1TB of space, although its VMDK is only 30GB. I want to shrink this down. I am following the instructions here (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Resizing_LVM-on-LUKS), but after I'm done, RHEL (the guest VM) sees the 1024GB partition, instead of the smaller version, and can't open it.

Sorry for the multiple screenshots, but this multistep process seems to deserve it.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: No, your partition (xvdb1) has been reduced to 326G according to your screenshot. Reducing the size of the device itself (xvdb) has to be done outside of the guest.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Please use [Markdown](http://serverfault.com/editing-help) and/or the formatting options in the edit menu to properly type-set your posts to improve their readability. Also use cut-and-paste for posting console output and format it as "`code`" rather than posting screenshots. That improves readability, attracts better answers  and allows indexing by search engines, which may help people with similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a new, smaller LUKS partition on a new virtual drive, copied the unencrypted contents to it, and auto-mounted it on boot instead of the old drive.